# UserControl in WinUI 3: how to set the 'source' property of an image and the 'click' event of a button?

Tags: c#, user-controls, winui-3

I'm building a UserControl that should display a button with an image and text.
I access that UserControl in the App like this:

```
<local:ButtonWithImage
ButtonClick="Button1_Click"
ButtonImage="Assets/Clipboard 4.png"
ButtonText="Clipboard History"
ButtonWidth="200" />
```

Out of the 4 properties displayed in the code above, two of them are working fine, which are ButtonText and ButtonWidth.
But the ButtonClick and ButtonImage properties are causing errors, which I'll explain next.

The UserControl code is this:

xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Launcher_WinUI3_Net_6.ButtonWithImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:Launcher_WinUI3_Net_6"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="button">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="image"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Height="1" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
public sealed partial class ButtonWithImage : UserControl
    {
        public ButtonWithImage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string ButtonText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty
        ButtonTextProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText",
        typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithImage), 
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ButtonTextValue));

        private static void ButtonTextValue(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var buttonWithImage = d as ButtonWithImage;
            var buttonWithImageProperty = buttonWithImage.FindName("textBlock") as TextBlock;
            buttonWithImageProperty.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }




        public string ButtonWidth
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty
        ButtonWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonWidth",
        typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithImage), 
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ButtonWidthValue));

        private static void ButtonWidthValue(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var buttonWithImage = d as ButtonWithImage;
            var buttonWithImageProperty = buttonWithImage.FindName("button") as Button;
            buttonWithImageProperty.Width = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue.ToString());
        }




        public string ButtonClick
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonClickProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonClickProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty
        ButtonClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonClick",
        typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ButtonClickValue));

        private static void ButtonClickValue(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var buttonWithImage = d as ButtonWithImage;
            var buttonWithImageProperty = buttonWithImage.FindName("button") as Button;
            buttonWithImageProperty.Click += e.NewValue.ToString();
        }







        public string ButtonImage
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty
        ButtonImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonImage",
        typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, ButtonImageValue));

        private static void ButtonImageValue(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var buttonWithImage = d as ButtonWithImage;
            var buttonWithImageProperty = buttonWithImage.FindName("image") as Image;
            buttonWithImageProperty.Source = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }





    }
```

The code for the **ButtonClick** is generating this error: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler'*

And the code for the **ButtonImage** is generating this error: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'*

I don't have much experience with creating UserControls so I'm following some examples I've seen on the internet, but none of them address these two problems I'm facing.

========================================================

Update 1 based on answer from Andrew KeepCoding:

Thanks Andrew!!!
There is still an error going on: *No overload for 'Button52_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'*

UserControl in the App:

```
<local:ButtonWithImage
ButtonImage="Assets/Clipboard 4.png"
ButtonText="Clipboard History"
ButtonWidth="200"
Click="Button52_Click" />
```

Button52_Click signature:

```
private void Button52_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foo();
}
```

UserControl 'Click' event signature:

```
public event EventHandler? Click;
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Click?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The signatures are the same, even so the error *No overload for 'Button52_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'* is occurring
The error is occurring here, in 'case 41:':

```
case 40: // MainWindow.xaml line 1288
{
  global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element40 = global::WinRT.CastExtensions.As<global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button>(target);
  ((global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element40).Click += this.Button51_Click;
}
break;

case 41: // MainWindow.xaml line 1199
{
  global::Launcher_WinUI3_Net_6.ButtonWithImage element41 = global::WinRT.CastExtensions.As<global::Launcher_WinUI3_Net_6.ButtonWithImage>(target);
  ((global::Launcher_WinUI3_Net_6.ButtonWithImage)element41).Click += this.Button52_Click;
}
break;
```

========================================================

Update 2:
The Button52_Click signature should be:

```
private void Button52_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foo();
}
```

And not:

```
private void Button52_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `typeof(string)`, you should use the actual type for your dependency properties.

For example, I'm using `ImageSource` for the `ButtonImage` in the code below:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControls.ButtonWithImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="button"
                Click="button_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image
                        x:Name="image"
                        Source="{x:Bind ButtonImage, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="textBlock"
                        Text="{x:Bind ButtonText, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Height="1" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System;

namespace UserControls;

public sealed partial class ButtonWithImage : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ButtonText),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ButtonWithImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ButtonImage),
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(ButtonWithImage),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public ButtonWithImage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler? Click;

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value);
    }

    public ImageSource? ButtonImage
    {
        get => (ImageSource?)GetValue(ButtonImageProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonImageProperty, value);
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<local:ButtonWithImage
    ButtonText="Text"
    ButtonImage="Assets/StoreLogo.png"
    Click="ButtonWithImage_Click" />
```

```cs
private void ButtonWithImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

You should also consider a custom control derived from a Button. These videos might help.

- [UserControls](https://youtu.be/AisI7MCVrC8)
- [CustomControls](https://youtu.be/yrW6Yt3tC7g)

Comment: I am very happy because your example is a true lesson and learning experience for me.
I added, following the example you gave, code for the 'Width' property and it worked perfectly too.
There is only one error occurring, with the Click event: No overload for 'Button52_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'
But I don't understand why this error is occurring, as the signature is correct.
I've updated my post to show where the error is occurring.

Comment: I updated my answer. The ``Click`` event in the ``ButtonWithImage`` user control is a simple event, not a ``RoutedEvent``. It's simpler this way.

Comment: Many thanks Andrew, your help will drastically reduce the amount of lines in the xaml code. Using this ControlUser plus the Styles and Resources the code will be reduced by about 70% or more.
Thank you very much for your help, it was a real lesson, I learned a lot from your guidance.
Have a Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!